# xpages required property for a combobox

Tags: dojo, xpages

There is a `djContainer` having multiple `djtabPane`(s).

A `combobox` is situated on the first `djtabPane`, having the property: `required="true"`.

but, when I move to next `djtabPane` in order to complete some other fields, I get the notification that the combobox value is required.

Can I achieve this property of the combobox but only if I want to submit / save the doc.?

```
<xe:djTabContainer id="djContentPane1" tabPosition="top" doLayout="false">
```

and the `djTabPane` ( all are the same, only the title is different ) :

```
<xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane1" title="Title1">
```

Comment: +1 because i have had the same question.  In fact, I got so fed up that I just started to make my own "validate" functions on save and doing it manually rather than relying on the standard functionality.

Comment: Dojo tab container and tab panes do not use partial refresh by default. Please add the code for your xe:djTabContainer and xe:djTabPane.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the validation to your save/submit method. A validator runs whenever a partial refresh happens unless you set immediate="true" or processValidators="false". But I don't think there's a way to set that on any of the in-built tabbed containers.

The advantage of Greg's approach when moving towards an MVC pattern is that the same validation can be run whenever saving the data object, not just from a specific XPage / Custom Control. The down-side is more work coding what's effectively in-built, e.g. tying the validation message back to the relevant component, setting the component's valid property to false etc.

Comment: Dojo tab container and tab panes do not use partial refresh by default. I agree with the approach to use "central" validation.